# Flask and MySQL, how to loop through the database to check if a user is in the table?

Tags: python, sql, database, flask

I set up this database on this website I'm building. When a user creates an account it is properly stored into the database. I'm now trying to get the login part of the website to work, but I'm unsure of how to loop through the database and see if the user email and password is present.

Here's my code for when a user registers:

```
@app.route("/SignUp", methods=['GET','POST'])
def Signup():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Welcome to the family {form.username.data}!','success')
        if request.method =='POST':
            userDetails = request.form
            user_name = userDetails['username']
            user_email = userDetails['email']
            user_password = userDetails['password']
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", 
            (user_name,user_email,user_password))

            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
            return redirect("Blog")
    return render_template("Register.html",form=form)
```

And here's my code for when a user signs in:

```
@app.route("/SignIn", methods=['GET','POST'])
def SignIn():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute
        flash('You have been Successfully Logged In!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('Blog'))
    else:
        flash('Unsuccessful, check your email and password!','danger')
    return render_template("SignIn.html",form=form)
```

I tried going finding how to loop through a database and learning about EXISTS in SQL but I can't find a proper way to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try executing the sql query as:

```
select user_name from users where user_name = '<your user name from login page>'
```

if you have a result, then user_name exists in database else doesnot exist.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried just now but i get this error MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'")

Comment: yeah, its a missing column in your database. Check your database table schema.